# How spring framework scans for the annotations and invokes action code for the annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations

I am trying to understand how Spring (Core spring part at least) works internally.

When we have an annotation like this:

```
@Autowired(required=true)
private JPADBAccess jPADBAccess;
```

**Which part of the Spring scans this annotation and invokes the code which does the work (in this case injecting the instance)?**

Does Spring scan the .class files looking for these annotations and then invoke the code which is supposed to do this work?

I really want to understand the core Spring, and the books which I refer, they don't tell all this (The internal workings or may be I haven't come across any book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand what happens behind the scene of the Spring Framework when it deals with @Autowired, you should do the following steps:

1. Download Spring source code and attach it to your favorite IDE. For example, in IDEA it is quite simple - just click the "Download sources" button on the Maven toolbar
2. Search in the Spring sources where the @Autowired is used (in IDEA, press Ctrl+Shift+F, select the "Custom" scope, choose the "Project and Libraries" option, in the "Text to find" type "Autowired.class", the press "Find". You will find all the occurences of the Autowired.class. Actually there will be a couple of occurences, choose the one from the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class. **This class exactly scans the @Autowired annotation**)
3. Set a breakpoint at the line where "Autowired.class" is used
4. Run your example Spring project in the debug mode (in IDEA, Shift+F9)

Once you application is started and the breakpoint is reached, you will see how Spring is scanning your bean where @Autowired dependency is declared.

Look at the "call stack" at the bottom left of the debug window and you will see list of invocations.

Press F8 in order to see how Spring scans your bean step-by-step.

All in all, if you want to understand how some stuff works in Java, just download the sources, set the breakpoints, and run sample project in debug mode.
If you have no sources for the library you want to study, just remember, you can decomile it (e.g. IDEA decompiles classes automatically).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did get your point for `@Autowired` annotation, the code in class `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` gets executed. However i still have doubt: Does this class get executed for  `@Autowired` annotation OR does it scan the code which has `@Autowired` annotation. I want to know which part of Spring scans the application code for the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Core Container does this job.
But it does not simply scan every class files to look for this @autowired annotation.
It only scans the class configured in your project configuration as Spring Beans.
Only objects managed by Spring IOC Container will be instantiated and dependencies  injected